# Apache not accepting connections

Tags: apache2

I'm running a Yii php web application on Ubuntu 12.04. It was working great for a while but now it refuses connects to port 80 about 80% of the time. Every once in a while it will work fine for a minute or two.

- Netstat says the port is listening.
- When I try to ncat to the port it says the target machine actively refused the connection.
- I have no iptables setup.
- The server is on a virtualbox vm running on a Windows 7 desktop. 
  I can ping the ubuntu vm from the desktop.

Here is my /etc/apache2.cfg

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5


<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}


AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files> 

DefaultType None


HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

Include httpd.conf

Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""      vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent


Include conf.d/

Include sites-enabled/
```

Most of the time it will refuse to connect, but sometimes it can load the index.html file, but none of my php files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have Skype on host or vm? Skype uses port 80 by default if not changed by the user.
It may interfere with your apache.

Comment: No skype is not installed on the vm or the desktop. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you installed apache on host OS?